# Codeigniter Pagination and MySQL Query with dynamic parameters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pagination

Let me explain my issue in detail

I have a table called products

```
Products : Name , views , sale_wanted , added_date
```

I am listing all my products in a view .
I am handling sale wanted through a flag means 0 or 1.
There are some links to sort the listing.

```
Most Viewed    
Wanted    
For Sale    
New Arrivals
```

Now when user clicks all the listing is sorted according to the parameter i am sendig.
I want to use pagination class of Codeigniter.
Here comes some issues.
When i am clicking let suppose Wanted and sending a parameter it lists all the products wanted.

```
Now i click on a pagination link and the wanted parameter is gone 
and the list becomes without wanted parameter.
```

Same goes with the other Anchors.
I have to restrict it so it still has my parameter.
The second problem is that what i see Codeigniter is laking.
I need some links that user can select. Means i want to give the user functionality to select how many products he wants to see in one page.

```
Let suppose 5 ,10 ,15 ,20
```

Choosing the greater number will reduce the number of pages.
And still i want the same functionality.
The important point is that i want to handle all this just in one shot means i dont want to duplicate my code for every anchor.
I need suggestions from expert and any help regarding Pagination library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the issue.

I have made two methods in Codeigniter Pagination library

Here they are

Defined two new variables

```
var $base_link  =   '';
var $per_page_link  =   TRUE;
var $per_page_array =   array();
```

The user can define both of them while initializing

```
$config['per_page_link']    =   TRUE;
$config['per_page_array']   =   array(5,10,15,20);
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Now the methods

```
public function create_per_page()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();

    $output =   '';
    $current    =   $CI->uri->segment(3,5);

    if($this->per_page_link === TRUE AND count($this->per_page_array) > 1){

        foreach($this->per_page_array as $row){

            if($current == $row){
                $output .=  $this->cur_tag_open . $row . $this->cur_tag_close;
                $output .=  '&nbsp;';                   
            }else{
                $output .=  '<a href="'.$this->base_link.$row.'/1">'.$row.'</a>';
                $output .=  '&nbsp;';
            }
        }

    }
    return  $output;
}
```

And the other is create_per_page_links(). I have just copied the code of create_links method in it and modified it. In the start of create_per_page_links() i have added these extra lines.

```
$this->per_page =   $CI->uri->segment(3,5);
$this->uri_segment  =   $CI->uri->segment(4,1);
```

However, This will only work with segments on. i haven't tested it with query string. Also if per_page_link is FALSE both methods will not work.
Calling create_per_page_links will generate the following

```
« First  < 1 2 3 4 5 >  Last »
```

And create_per_page will generate the following

```
5 10 15 20
```

And Done

Answer (score 0):

```
$seg=3
$noOfresultsToshow=$this->uri->segment('5')//use if else for by default no of results
$typeOfresult=$this->uri->segment('4'); //Most Viewed Wanted For Sale    New Arrivals
$config['total_rows'] = $countqueryresults;// mention the total rows here
$config['per_page'] = $noOfresultsToshow;
$config['uri_segment'] = $seg;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['yourvariable'] = $this->model_name->getData($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment($seg),$typeOfresult);
$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

in your view file `echo $links;`